# MSI/WiX - Should ProductCode change between builds?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, versioning

I'm using WiX to create an installer for my project, and I'm a bit confused about what ProductCode should do.

It seems that the preferred behaviour in WiX is to not set the ProductCode manually, and just let it generate a new GUID every time I rebuild the MSI for a new release, regardless of what has changed. In fact, the default WiX project in visual studio specifies an UpgradeCode but it doesn't specify a ProductCode.

This works fine, but I thought that a ProductCode was used as the main identifier for an application in Windows regardless of version or build, and so surely it shouldn't regenerate every time an update is shipped?

Also if I want to read info about an application from the registry such as its name, version or uninstall string, I have to search for its ProductCode under *Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall* - so it seems that the code should be consistent, right? Or maybe there's a better way to look up info about a program from the registry.

So which interpretation is right - should it be fixed or change between builds?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of the following scenarios when you want your product code to be fixed (specified manually):

- You have some other product that is looking for your product one by code in the registry. To check if it is installed, for example. There is a Windows Installer API available to look for an installed product by product code. Also, the standard MSI action "FindRelatedProducts" uses product codes. This may be useful when you want to uninstall not your product but somebody else's other product on your product installation.
- You use an update mode different from the default "major update" when a previous product is completely uninstalled and then a new version is installed (i.e. you use something like "patches" or "minor updates", when only some components of the product are updated). Please note that most of the products don't use this special mode.

Anyway, all these scenarios are marginal, I would rely on the default behavior unless you know what you are doing and why. This default behavior is fine.

Please note that product code MUST be changed for major updates (which is the most common type of update), and this behavior ensures it is.